# Is there a way to git fetch and only get the history - no files

Tags: git, github, git-clone

I'm creating a service that analyzes git repository logs, so I'd like to be able to clone down a repository's history without the files to save space. Is that possible?

Comment: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone: look for the -n option.

Comment: You want to just download the .git/refs folder. You can just get this not 100% sure how to ATM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command

```
git clone -n
```

works well enough. Thanks @JB Nizet!

Comment: This still downloads the files. It just doesn't check them out

Comment: @exussum yes but they live compressed inside of the folder, rather than uncompressed - and I need access to the diffs anyway, so this might be okay.

Answer (score 1):

As you found out you have to use the following command:

```
git clone -n
```

> **-n / --no-checkout**
>
> No checkout of HEAD is performed after the clone is complete.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible with git protocol, but for github, it's doable with API:

https://api.github.com/repos/git/git/commits?per_page=100
https://api.github.com/repos/git/git/commits?per_page=100&page=2

and so on.